# Comparing binary matrices and weights

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, binary

If two $n×m$ binary matrices have the same row weights, column weights, upper-diagonal weights and lower-diagonal weights, are they necessarily identical?

The weight of a given row, column, or diagonal is the number of entries with $1$ in that row, column, or diagonal.

The following matrix:$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has the row, column, and diagonal weights:

**Row:** $2, 2, 2$

**Col:** $2, 2, 2$

**Upper diagonal:** $1, 0, 3, 2, 0$

**Lower diagonal:** $1, 1, 2, 1, 1$

At first I considered only when the row and column weights are the same. I found a counter example. Then I considered only when the upper and lower diagonals weights. Yet again, I found a counter example.

How can one going about proving it? Or does anyone have a counter example?
I have no been able to find one thus far.

Comment: What do these weights even mean?

Comment: Pigeonhole proof: there are $2^{n^2}$ such matrices, but at most $(n+1)^{6n}$ such configurations of weights ($n+n+2n+2n$ different weights, each of which takes a value in $\{0,\dots,n\}.$ The $2^{n^2}$ is bigger for sufficiently large $n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$